# Publish Program - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want publish my program in Visual Studio but the menu "publish" with blue icon don't show up. Only this...[image]

But i want this

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Publish" it in what way?  What kind of project is it?  Can you provide information about the project itself?

Comment: I think if I see the project correctly it is an uwp project. Where do you want to publish it? Because if you hover over the publish an press create app packages. Then you create an app package you can install on another computer.

Comment: @Codeaur Oh! Yes it's a UWP project, is normal !!! Ok, ok, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to the comments：**

This is because of the uwp project.This is normal.